# imagick.so.so after brew update + php.ini "imagick.so" instead of imagick.so

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I did a `brew upgrade`
I have php 8.1 on osx 12.x

Imagick is not working

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/8.1
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

My thinking is the relevant error is about `/usr/local/lib/imagick.so.so` and I have a file `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so` that might be better to link against.

- I also noticed that inside my `php.ini` I got `extension="imagick.so"` which I renamed `extension=imagick.so`
- if I `ls /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/` I get no file
  now if I `ls /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/` then use autocompletion to finish `20210902` I get `imagick.so`

I tried making a symlink in `/usr/local/lib/` but it does not work. What is the way to resolve errors like this?

tried to symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so /usr/lib/imagick.so` but I get operation not permited

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so /usr/local/lib/imagick.so
ls: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so: No such file or directory
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  43 Dec  1 10:58 /usr/local/lib/imagick.so -> /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/*/imagick.so
-rw-r--r--  1 ed  admin  438784 Jun 16 17:25 /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imagick.so
```

I did What @nohillside suggested below and while this solved the issue I believe there is still an issue related to the same problem

php --ini

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I try reinstalling by `pecl uninstall imagick` but I get same error

```
pecl uninstall imagick
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imagick.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imagick.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/imagemagick/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib' (no such file)), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/imagick.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

if I do ls /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/ I get two versions 20190902 20210902

Comment: There seems to be an incompatibility between the installed versions of PHP and imagemagick. Maybe removing/uninstalling everything and reinstalling it is easier than trying to fix this.

Comment: @nohillside yes I agree this is why I tried to uninstall imagick but as you can see I cannot anymore. `pecl uninstall` fails. I am not sure how to go about that? I already uninstalled imagemagick with homebrew. how can the uninstaller be broken ? Should I delete files manually ? which files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details matter, `20210902` isn't the same as `20190902` :-)

Run

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/imagick.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imagick.so /usr/local/lib/imagick.so
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/imagick.so
```

Comment: Your answer solved the issue I believe but also revealed another one; PHP is still confused with those two versions :) I updated the question, let me know if this is unrelated and I will accept your solution as it is.

Comment: I cannot uninstall imagick with pecl :) updated the question

Comment: to make it work in the end I had to did what you said but with 20290902 after reinstalling everything a million times